# ASP.NET - dynamically display matches as user types text into a field

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, textbox

I want to display a list of name matches from the database when user types text into a field.

In `WinForms` I simply set a filter of the underlying `datasource`.

How to get this to work in `ASP.NET` without refreshing the web page?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at [Jquery UI AutoComplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) .  As far as retrieving data it would be best to do ajax.  If you dont already have services you could simply create a page method on your page.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetResults()
{
    return "something";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Ajax Auto Complete](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)**

Try this `ASP.NET Ajax control`.

It does exactly what you are looking for.

You will have to download Ajax Toolkit.

**[Download Link](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/)**.

Follow on the steps to use the control.

You will have to write a `Web Service` which will retrieve the matches from the database.

Comment: If the poster is most comfortable with asp.net controls and not so much with writing his own javascript I would say this is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @latr0dectus Ya if there is a control ready made that can be used then why not?